# default_scope rails alternative

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, default-scope

I have a database of users that uses my system once, and then I don't see them again for another 4-5 years, so I thought to myself why not "archive" all those users and only focus on the most recent ones, the ones `last_sign_in_at >= DateTime.now - 10.days`.
I have an admin tools that uses rails_admin, and that would have been perfect to work with 5% of the DB rather than a 100%.

I did some searching and I found `default_scope` unfortunately I very quickly found that it was pure evil.

What would you recommend in this situation ?

thanks for your help

Comment: Why not just sort on `last_sign_at`? Rails_admin uses pagination, so you will see the recent users first.

Comment: cause it's not just about rails_admin

Comment: But where in your application does it really hurt to fetch all the users?

Comment: actually, no where in particular but I thought that it could only improve the performance to "reduce" the size of the DB

Comment: Then you are solving a non-existent problem. ;)